# What font-families should I use to display all major languages in my pdf in all operating systems?

Tags: fonts

I'm currently working on a project to convert HTML content to PDF using Apache FOP. I'm working with different languages and I'm not sure if the font-family that I'm using will work on linux. I don't have access to a linux machine right now.

I'm using the  feature in fop configuration to pick fonts from the respective OS.

Right now I'm using Arial,MS Mincho,sans-serif families. But MS Mincho comes with office package. So I fear Languages such as Japanese and Chinese will not be rendered in Linux. Are there any other families common to both OSs?

Comment: PDF supports embedded fonts: if you have fonts that allow embedding and Apache FOP supports embedding you can avoid the issue...

Comment: Simply subset-embed all the fonts your PDF file actually uses.